# Build script for react UI component library

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-starter-kit

I'm new to Webpack and to be honest it still confuses me slightly. I would like to create a shareable UI component library from my react build (Using react-starter-kit as it's base). Is there a way to configure my webpack config to output files that I can then import as an NPM module to another project and import the components?

Current setup source folder:

```
├── /src/                   # The source code of the application
│  ├── /components/         # React components
│  │   ├── /ComponentName   # Component
│  │   ├── index.js         Exports all components
```

Using the default setup of react starter kit..it's default webpack.config:
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js

If I run the build script as /components/index.js as an entry point the resultant script doesn't give me what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle this in my [React component boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate) in a couple of ways. I've tried to cover the basic ideas below so you can adapt as needed.

### UMDified `dist` versions

Set [output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) to `umd`. This will write a wrapper you can import from various environments (AMD, CommonJS, global). Set `output.library` to match the global name of your library.

**webpack.config.js**

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  library: 'MyAwesomeLibrary'
}
```

I have set up separate targets for generating a non-minified and a minified version of my component. I include these to the version control when publishing so they are easy for people to find and use.

### Node Version Through Babel

To make it easy to consume the package through Node and Webpack, I process my code through Babel instead of Webpack. This keeps the file structure intact. Alternatively you could just point to the generated `dist` but I find this option neater given it provides more flexibility. You can import features outside of your entry point when doing it like this.

To achieve this, I've set it up as follows:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dist:modules": "babel ./src --out-dir ./dist-modules"
}
```

This tells Babel to pick up my source and write it to `./dist-modules`. I've `.gitignore`d the directory. It will be included only in the published version and generated on demand by a `postinstall` script should it not exist. This can happen if you consume a package through version control instead of npm.

### Conclusion

These are the basic ideas. Study the [boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate) for more specific details.

Comment: Thank you! I'd prefer to go down the package.json route. But trying to create a script that replicates what webpack is doing is proving to be very difficult. Babel + PostCSS + css modules + react inline imports = headache!

Comment: It's definitely a lot of technology to integrate. I wrote [a chapter](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/authoring_libraries/) that digs deeper in the topics. Good luck. :)